# Calling a wordpress plugin in the header with a hook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I have this plugin https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wayne-audio-player/ that is called in the footer but i need it to be in my header.
I've managed to do that easily with some css.
But then i've noticed this line:

```
 add_action('wp_footer', 'wayne_audio_player_markup');
```

So i tried this:

```
add_action('get_header', 'wayne_audio_player_markup');
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I would like to know if there's a way of calling this plugin in the header without css code.

Comment: The 'get_header' worked but it's not exactly what i need. I've found something about the '__after_header' hook that may fit my needs, but the plugin do not display. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok i've found another solution. Just put "<?php do_action(my_custom_hook);" ?> wherever you want. Then call your hook in your .php file like this: add_action('my_custom_hook', 'my_function');
And that's it !

Comment: I plugin cannot get 'called' in the footer. Perhaps you can rephrase?

Comment: This plugin was 'called' in the footer as you can see in the original line code above with 'wp_footer'. I just tested it and the player displays below the 'footer' tag and below my GA 'script' tag. @JimMaguire

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
remove_action('wp_footer', 'wayne_audio_player_markup');
add_action('wp_head', 'wayne_audio_player_markup');
```

With [remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) you can unregister any previously hooked functions.

Comment: Ok thanks ! But the 'wp_head' hook display the player in the very top of my viewport so it wasn't exactly what i was looking for.
But i'll add the remove_action to make it cleaner thanks :)